# Can I cache value on Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype) hook?

Tags: javascript, hook, userscripts

I am working a on browser userscript, but it use React and Webpack internally.
But I want to get a props of a component, so I come up this idea:

```
let value
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'props',{
    set: v=>{
        console.log(v)
        value=v
    },
    get: ()=>value
})
```

But it doesn't works for multiple object:

```
let a={}
let b={}
a.props='hello' //console.log('hello')
console.log(b.props) //hello
```

So is there a way to know which object triggered the hook?
I want to cache that in an object.

Comment: You're looking for `this`.  But your cache is pointless.

Comment: This is an "XY problem" if there ever was one.

Comment: @BrockAdams Is there a better way to get React component's props in this case?